# dd/cat luks lvm on drive that has larger total size (partition plus trailing empty space) into smaller drives that can hold said luks lvm?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, encryption

I have three drives, 256gb, 128gb and 120gb. My encrypted LVM is 115gb in size. In a gui disk utility, it shows that I have trailing space after the encrypted partition, but I'm not sure if the physical layout of the data is the same as well.

How can I clone the lvm between them for backups and to test performance safely?

I've checked Gparted, but it doesn't seem to let me copy the drive. If I let dd/cat run until it is out of space when drives are larger than the destination, would the data be transferred satisfactorily?

What I want to be able to do is dd/cat from any drive to any of the others.

```
128GB > 120GB
120GB > 128GB
120GB > 250GB
etcGB > etcGB
```

Comment: lvm kind of gives me a headache... I think they can be set up to span several physical drives, so I'm not sure how yours is set up. Or if it's LVM on top of LUKS, or vice versa. *If* you can get a volume (in the lvm, like a partition *I think*) to be small enough to fit on any other physical drive, then I think you could just copy it (with `dd` or even `cat`). *If* they were just plain LUKS containers, then just copying them should work... If there's anything important at all on any drives, do make a backup before experimenting.

Comment: Its default from Debian installer, "Encrypted LVM" on a single drive. Currently I'm just making backups to a encrypted repository until system is stable enough, may take till next weekend to test out. I think Clonezilla could be an option, but that requires more work than dd/cat.